# How to sum and count Id's of different tables from a Union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables **councils**, **station_levy**, **market_levy**, *and the station table is joined to get councils in station_levy*.
I need to get data by council sum the number of station_levy + market_levy and get the total amount tendered.

Tables are as follows

```
councils
---------------+----------+
| council_id   | Name     |
+--------------+----------+
| 1            | LSK      |
---------------+----------+
| 2            | KBW      |
---------------+----------+


station_levy
------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| station_levy_id | station_id  | amount_tendered |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       1         |   3         |    10.00        |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       2         |   3         |    10.00        |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       3         |   1         |    5.00         |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+


(station_id = 1 is found in the LSK council_id=1  And station_id = 3 is found in the KBW council_id=2)

market_levy
------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| market_levy_id  | council_id  | amount_tendered |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       1         |   1         |    5.00         |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       2         |   2         |    5.00         |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|       3         |   1         |    5.00         |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

mysql

```
SELECT c.council_name, (COUNT(market_levy.market_levy_id)+ COUNT(st.station_levy_id )) count, SUM(amount_tendered) revenue
    FROM councils c 
    JOIN (
        (SELECT council_id, amount_tendered,market_levy_id  FROM market_levy  WHERE transaction_date >= CURDATE() )
        UNION ALL

        (SELECT station_levy_id , councils.council_id, amount_tendered 
        FROM station_levy st     
        JOIN stations ON stations.station_id = st.station_id
        JOIN councils ON councils .council_id= stations .council_id
        WHERE transaction_datetime >= CURDATE()
    )) totalCouncilRevenue USING (council_id)
    group by council_id, c.council_name ORDER BY SUM(amount_tendered) DESC
```

Expected result

```
------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| council_name    | count       | revenue         |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|      LSK        |   3         |    15.00        |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
|      KBW        |   3         |    25.00        |
+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: The tables `transactions` and `transactions_station_levy` are missing from your sample data. Can you please add them?

Comment: `MONTH(transaction_date) = CURDATE()` cannot work. It will compare a month number, e.g. `9`, with a date, e.g. `DATE '2020-09-02'`.

Comment: And when showing a query, you should tell us why it doesn't work for you. Do you get an error message or too many rows or too few rows or a wrong sum or what else?

Comment: I forget  to properly edit the query

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Im getting this error  => `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'st.station_levy_id' in 'field list'` , but if i run with only `COUNT(market_levy.market_levy_id)` it works

Comment: The version is `mysql-5.7` i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing columns in your `UNION ALL` matching `council_id` with `station_levy_id`, `amount_tendered` with `council_id`, and `market_levy_id` with `amount_tendered`.

Then, in your main query you try to access `market_levy.market_levy_id` and `st.station_levy_id`, but these columns are not accessible, as you select from a subquery called `totalCouncilRevenue`, not from tables labelled `market_levy` and `st` there.

Your query fixed:

```
SELECT 
  c.council_name, 
  COUNT(*) AS transaction_count,
  SUM(amount_tendered) AS revenue
FROM councils c 
JOIN
(
  SELECT council_id, amount_tendered
  FROM market_levy  
  WHERE transaction_date >= CURDATE() 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.council_id, st.amount_tendered 
  FROM station_levy st    
  JOIN stations s ON s.station_id = st.station_id
  WHERE st.transaction_datetime >= CURDATE()
) totalCouncilRevenue USING (council_id)
GROUP BY council_id, c.council_name 
ORDER BY SUM(amount_tendered) DESC;
```

I prefer aggregating before joining, though:

```
SELECT 
  c.council_name, 
  COALESCE(t1.cnt, 0) + COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS transaction_count,
  COALESCE(t1.total, 0) + COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS revenue
FROM councils c 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT council_id, SUM(amount_tendered) as total, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM market_levy  
  WHERE transaction_date >= CURDATE() 
  GROUP BY council_id
) t1 USING (council_id)
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT s.council_id, SUM(st.amount_tendered) as total, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM station_levy st    
  JOIN stations s ON s.station_id = st.station_id
  WHERE st.transaction_datetime >= CURDATE()
  GROUP BY s.council_id
) t2 USING (council_id)
ORDER BY revenue DESC;
```

Such queries are usually less prone to errors and are sometimes faster, because they may be able to use indexes more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, this Exactly what I was expecting